# Parametrix of external product of elliptic operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $S$ and $T$ be Dirac-type operators on vector bundles $E\rightarrow M$ and $F\rightarrow N$ respectively, where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds. Suppose $Q_S$ and $Q_T$ are parametrices for $S$ and $T$. Form the operator $S\#T$ on the external product bundle $E\boxtimes F\rightarrow M\times N$, defined as 
$$S\#T=S\otimes 1+1\otimes T.$$

Then $S\#T$ is an elliptic operator and has a parametrix $Q_{S\#T}$ so that

$$1-Q_S S,\qquad 1-Q_T T,\qquad 1-Q_{S\#T}(S\#T),$$
$$1-S Q_S,\qquad 1-T Q_T,\qquad 1-(S\#T)Q_{S\#T}$$
have smooth Schwartz kernels.

**Question:** How can one construct $Q_{S\#T}$ using $Q_S$ and $Q_T$ so that one can relate the Schwartz kernel of, say $1-Q_{S\#T}(S\#T)$, to those of $1-Q_S S$ and $1-Q_T T$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is $S\#T$ elliptic?

Comment: As a post with similar terminologies please see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266734/the-sum-of-linear-partial-differential-operators-of-equal-strength#comment755160_266734

Comment: @DeaneYang  one can ask the same question  in the context of fredholm operators on Hilber spaces is $S\#T$ a fredholm operator if both $S$ and $T$ are Fredholm operators on hilbert spaces $H_1,H_2$, respectively?

Comment: @DeaneYang You're right, it doesn't in general need to be elliptic. Let's specialise to Dirac-type operators.

Comment: I haven't tried to do it myself, but it seems like you could do this by the usual approach using the symbol calculus for pseudodifferential operators.

Comment: Right, what I want to do is to relate the Schwartz kernel of $R=1-Q_{S\# T}S\# T$ to those of $1-Q_S S$ and $1-Q_T T$, in order to calculate the trace of $R$ along the diagonal.